# Warning: Illegal string offset (seems it's quite different)

Tags: php

Hi i know there is an answer of this question but it seems i've a different kind of problem there. have a look please. Code is given below

**PHP**

```
if(!$_POST["name"]){
    $error="Please enter your name";
}

if(!$_POST["email"]){
    $error="Please enter your email";
}

if(!$_POST["txtarea"]){
    $error="Please enter comments";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="formgroup">
            <label for="name">Your name</label>
            <input type ="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="your name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="formgroup">
            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type ="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="your email"/>
        </div>

        <div class="formgroup">
            <label for="txtarea">Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="tar" ></textarea>
        </div>
```

> formgroup class is used for bootstrap

Have a look please don't know what to do next i'm beginner so please pardon if i didn't get this question from previous one

Comment: What is your question about that code?

Comment: See this part Related to the right of your question? --->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether it is set or not

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){    
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use $_POST["tar"] in place of $_POST["txtarea"].
```

> Blockquote Cause you have that name(tar) in your form

Comment: bro illegal offset string occurring in name, email, and txtarea in all

Comment: Also , Use isset() method before any operation.

Comment: are you checking after posting form?

Comment: $_POST["name"]=isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '';

I tried this too but didn't work for me this

Answer (score 0):

**IN HTML**

```
<div class="formgroup">
            <label for="txtarea">Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="tar" ></textarea>
        </div>
```

**IN PHP**

```
if(!$_POST["txtarea"]){
    $error="Please enter comments";
}
```

In html you used tar as a name and in php you used different name txtarea

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){    
 if(!$_POST["name"]){
 $error="Please enter your name";
 }
}
```